# Update two table with double rows

Tags: oracle, double, appearance

(ORACLE)
Dear,
I have tbA :

| ID | map |
| --- | --- |
| 1 |  |
| 2 |  |
| 2 |  |
| 2 |  |
| 2 |  |
| 3 |  |
| 3 |  |
| 4 |  |
| 5 |  |

(1.5 million rows!!) Id 1, 2, 3 is example (it's contain a-z… not only number-can not use min max)

tbB :

| ID | map |
| --- | --- |
| 2 |  |
| 2 |  |
| 2 |  |
| 3 |  |
| 3 |  |
| 3 |  |
| 5 |  |

(1.2 million rows)

And I want update value on tbA and tbB

tbA :

| ID | map |
| --- | --- |
| 1 |  |
| 2 | ok |
| 2 | ok |
| 2 | ok |
| 2 |  |
| 3 | ok |
| 3 | ok |
| 4 |  |
| 5 | ok |

tbB :

| ID | map |
| --- | --- |
| 2 | ok |
| 2 | ok |
| 2 | ok |
| 3 | ok |
| 3 | ok |
| 3 |  |
| 5 | ok |

Please help me SQL to update it.

I plan to numbering appearance:

| ID | map | App |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 |  | 1 |
| 2 |  | 1 |
| 2 |  | 2 |
| 2 |  | 3 |
| 2 |  | 4 |
| 3 |  | 1 |
| 3 |  | 2 |
| 4 |  | 1 |
| 5 |  | 1 |

And get key = id & app to compare but how to? Or please help me SQL to update it.
Note: table has many rows (>1m rows)

Please help me,
Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Match using the `ID` column and the `ROW_NUMBER` analytic function to ensure each `ID` has a unique incrementing value:

```sql
UPDATE tba
SET map = 'ok'
WHERE ROWID IN (
  SELECT a.rid
  FROM   (
           SELECT ROWID AS rid,
                  id,
                  ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY ROWNUM) AS rn
           FROM   tba
         ) a
         INNER JOIN (
           SELECT id,
                  ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY ROWNUM) AS rn
           FROM   tbb
         ) b
         ON a.id = b.id AND a.rn = b.rn
);
```

For `tbb` then swap `tba` and `tbb` and the corresponding aliases wherever they occur.

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/H2wa-c9Z)